# Generate statistics from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, statistics

**First of all about the setup:**
*Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Php: 5.4.4-14+deb7u9

MySQL: 5.5.38*

The website is used by employees to track their daily work. I started building up some statistic-pages in html/php to get a monthly overview. I noticed this will get bigger and bigger as I really need a lot of statistics.

Isnt there any plugin/addon/application to automaticly create statistics?
The most time I spend is for building up the pages and creating comfortable layouts to read the statistics. Thats wasting time. The calculations for itself are easy.

So in other words: Im looking for some application that provides a already finished interface which just needs to be filled with formulas to generate statistics from a mysql-db. Its just about saving time by not having to build up every layout for every new statistic-page.

I already searched for this a lot but without success. The most people are talking about how to write this in php for themself. Thats exactly what Im NOT searching for. :)

*I'm looking forward hearing your suggestions to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a search for 'HTML template GUI charts' on google. Incorporate that template to your code and you're done...

I've found the following result, which looks promising, but I haven't checked out the code yet:
http://www.egrappler.com/free-premium-html-adminbackend-template-for-web-applications-bluewhale-admin/

Comment: For the first look, blue whale really looks nice. Ill check that out, thanks.

Comment: Alright, Ill use blueWhale for the moment. The most things I need are already coded in this template. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same feeling, of wasting time, building a nice GUI to deliver results from simple code some time back. But just as programmers make libs and share/sell them to each other to enhance productivity, so do designers.

Search for Admin Panel and / or take a look at the selection from my favorite design site: http://themeforest.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=panel

Comment: Thanks for the link, havnt known the website before. Looks useful.